# Autochange location of element in windows forms application

Tags: c#, forms, location, windows-forms-designer

I put pictureboxes in windows form by dragging them using visual studio. Form opens in full screen mode, but picturebox which was located in top right side of windows, appears in top-center part of window as shown below.

[image]

So, what to do to make picturebox appear in top right side of window as I located in visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

use Anchor:

select the control and change the property [Anchor] to the desired style - should be top-right

Answer (score 1):

Define Anchors and Margins for controls you want to stick. Margin define how far control is from borders defined in Anchor property.